# Android w React-Native: secure fetch request fails

Tags: android, ssl, react-native, https

I'm working on a native app for iOS and Android using React-Native. I have to hit a third-party REST API that uses https:// protocol. There is a staging server and a production server for the API.

I have success making requests to both servers on iOS. On Android, I can access staging, but not production. Requests to both servers are successful using Postman.

Requests to production on Android give me the infamous [TypeError: Network request failed] message. I looked around on this site and elsewhere, and learned that this is usually the result of a certificate trust issue (which is not something I'm super knowledgeable about). I used openssl to view the certificates and did see three certs when checking staging, and only two for production. I tried following the custom TrustManager example on the Android HTTPS and SSL page: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

As well as this tutorial for SSL pinning: https://medium.com/the-many/a-year-of-react-native-ssl-pinning-3801a973cbfe

No luck. I should probably mention that at no point have I seen any logcat messages referring to certificate trust errors, so I'm not even entirely sure this is my issue.. it's just the only thing that makes sense based on what I've been able to find out. I tried going to Android Studio Preferences > Tools > Server Certificates and enabled 'Accept non-trusted certificates automatically' as a sanity check for testing. Still no luck and no change in log messages.

The requests are formatted exactly the same in React-Native, and are successful in three out of four of my scenarios (iOS staging & prod, Android staging). What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide some details about the 3 party api you are using? What are the difference between their production/test server?

Comment: I don't know much about their server setups. I've reached out for info, but haven't heard back.

Comment: Have you found a solution?